# List mimetypes that default to a given .desktop file

Tags: mime-types, freedesktop, gvfs, xdg

I can list the mimetypes potentially handled by a `.desktop` file doing something like this:

```
$ grep 'MimeType' /usr/share/applications/eog.desktop | tr ';' '\n'
MimeType=image/bmp
image/gif
image/jpeg
image/jpg
image/pjpeg
image/png
image/tiff
...
```

And I can show what the default application is for a given mimetype with `gvfs-mime`:

```
$ gvfs-mime --query image/tiff
Default application for 'image/tiff': eog.desktop
Registered applications:
        eog.desktop
        gimp.desktop
...
Recommended applications:
        eog.desktop
        gimp.desktop
...
```

or with `gio`:

```
$ gio mime image/tiff
Default application for “image/tiff”: eog.desktop
Registered applications:
    eog.desktop
    gimp.desktop
...
Recommended applications:
    eog.desktop
    gimp.desktop
...
```

But how do I list the mimetypes that `eog.desktop` actually handles?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't know of any tool that does that.
You could write your own though. Here is a very simple python3 script that should run on any system that uses [*GIO*](https://developer.gnome.org/gio/stable/ch01.html) underneath (e.g. Gnome 3):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from sys import argv
from gi.repository import Gio

app = argv[1]
glauncher = Gio.DesktopAppInfo.new_from_filename(app)
for mtype in Gio.AppInfo.get_supported_types(glauncher):
    ghandler = Gio.AppInfo.get_default_for_type(mtype, False)
    launcher = glauncher.get_executable()
    handler = ghandler.get_executable()
    if launcher == handler:
        print (mtype)
```

The script takes one argument: the full path to your desktop file

```
myscript /usr/share/applications/eog.desktop
```

The script gets the list of mime types that your application supports, then, for each item in the list, it gets the default handler and if it's the same application, it prints the mime type.

---

I guess you could also try to parse `mimeapps.list`, `mimeinfo.cache` or `defaults.list` (the latter is deprecated, see [freedesktop.org spec](http://standards.freedesktop.org/mime-apps-spec/mime-apps-spec-1.0.html) for possible file names and locations) and extract the relevant information from there but your results may vary as on some distros some of those files are missing.

Comment: I was hoping a command could check the appropriate files and handle precedence automatically, but this is a good explanation for how to do it manually.

Comment: @bariumbitmap - I don't know of any command that does what you want, I have updated my post though.

Comment: That does the trick. I happen to use XFCE, but all I needed was the `python-gi` package, so life is good.