# List all filename extension associations for a given program

Tags: xdg-open, file-types

Is there a way of getting all `xdg-open`'s file name extensions that are associated with a given application, eg:

```
.html -> firefox.desktop
.htm  -> firefox.desktop
```

Comment: Almost a dupe of [List mimetypes that default to a given .desktop file](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/228720)

Comment: Problem is that Linux uses the mime type NOT the extension (windows uses the extension)